# How to Query Posts if Post Meta Value is multidimensional array?

Tags: wordpress

I was using the following meta Query, but I'm still getting irrelevant posts.

```
$current_query['meta_query'] = array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => '_game_selected_platforms',
                                    'value' => $platform->term_id,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                            );
```

Whereas the meta value was multidimensional array as follows:

```
get_post_meta('$postID','_game_selected_platforms',false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what i did. i used the **pre_get_posts** filter, to further dig into that array and search if the value exist, then i used **post__in**

```
function latest_articles_of_platform($query){
    $platformobject = get_query_var('get_latest_articles');
    global $wpdb;
    $getallposts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'", OBJECT );
    if ($getallposts){
        $postsin = array();
        foreach ($getallposts as $getallpost)   {
            $platformsofposts = get_post_meta($getallpost->ID,'_game_selected_platforms',false);
            if(in_array($platformsofposts->term_id, $platformsofposts ) ){
                $postsin[] = $getallpost->ID;
            }
        }
    } // if $getallposts

    if (get_query_var('get_latest_articles')) {
    //  var_dump($getallposts);
        $query->set('post__in',$postsin);
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'latest_articles_of_platform' );
```

I was searching for help with existing topic but i did not get any solution.

 **IMPORTANT**

```
$current_query['get_latest_articles'] = $platform;
```

I have also added this line in query to identify that it is my custom query but this is only possible if you have access to front end query otherwise there are other methods to identify if it that query which you want to filter.